# Testing the Ruby on Rails weblog(netbeans edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

I recently started learning ruby on rails. I completed the weblog walkthru(links below) and want to make tests for it. I took this functional testing from the video version of the weblog demo. Now i want to make this testing work for the netbeans edition, which actually is structured differently in terms of how the comments relates to the post. From what I gathered, in the netbeans version, all comment views are done through the posts views. Now this test method needs to be modified to accomodate for that. How would I create the post object with a comment also? I dont know how objects work in Ruby. Like how to instantiate and such.

```
  test "should create comment and redirect to post without javascript" do
 p= Post.create!(:title => 'hello',:body => 'world')
 post :create, :post_id => p.id, :comment => {:body =>'nice!'}
 assert_redirected_to post_url(p)
 assert_equal 'nice!',p.comments.first.body
end
```

- http://www.netbeans.org/kb/61/ruby/rapid-ruby-weblog.html#08
- http://www.netbeans.org/kb/61/ruby/model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, you are trying to imitate a user submitting a comment on existing post. What you can do is run the project, open your web page, navigate to a post and create a comment. Then, check the server log file and find the part that was caused by you posting that comment. There you will see something like this:

```
Processing PostsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-06-27 16:54:18) [POST]
Session ID: 17134c01441c1e26e17baeee4681dd3b
Parameters: {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"posts", "comment"=> {"foo" => "bar"}}
```

Then just imitate that in your test, by writing something like:

```
post :create, :comment => {:foo => "bar"}
```

And that should create a new comment on the post.

However, you should do it this way **ONLY WHILE LEARNING!** Once you have got the hang of things, write tests before, outline how it all *should* work, and then work on the implementation until it does.

Comment: Where would I find the server log file?

Comment: By default it is in PROJECT_DIR/log, look for development.log. Also, you should be able to see what gets written there at runtime, depending on how you start the server - the same terminal window where you wrote 'script/server', if you start it up that way. I think netbeans had some sort of in-build server console too, if you launch the server by some IDE command - haven't used NB in ages.